# Windows Server Security/System Log Access Auditing

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to analyze the logs of my 2 servers, one Win 2k8 R2 and the other Win 2k3. Specifically, I would like to be able to see in the logs if a user deleted, accessed, or modified either the Security Event or System Event logs. I found this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315508(v=ws.10).aspx) that has an event code for when a log is cleared, and was wondering if there was some way to see if a log was accessed through Event Viewer. I haven't been able to find a code for simply accessing these logs through Event Viewer. And as far as I am aware, a user should not be able to modify the contents of this two log files other than clearing them, correct? Just to be clear, I want to know if a user is in Event Viewer and looking through these audit logs.

Comment: I'm not sure (hence not posting this as an answer), but I believe you'd have to enable file system auditing and monitor those logs for access to the event log files/folder.  [This link gives you a basic how-to on auditing file access](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/08/27/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers.aspx)... it's for file servers, but the same principles apply, and I'm sure it's every bit as much of a pain in the ass to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. I'm just wondering if monitoring the .evtx file will just show that some system account is accessing it rather than a user account since the viewing is being done through Event Viewer.

Comment: You'll get the user account accessing it.  Would kind of defeat the whole purpose of having permissions on files if you could sidestep them by using a different application, wouldn't it?

Comment: I see. I'll see if setting up log file monitoring works then.